# How to expand link on hoover? Add "<" ">" symbols around link?

Tags: html, css

How can I make some symbols appear around my links on mouse over? For example I have some link:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>&LT;</span>Home<span>&GT;</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paintings</a></li>
</ul>
```

I mean I want these "< >" to slowly expand from behind the link then I hoover it. And to go back in and hide after I move mouse away. I know about css transitions and animations. I tried many ways but it does not work. Best result was when I used small images and opacity. But its not what I want. I want some nice smooth movement from behind link.

**EDIT:**
Well, after some time in google I come across  this website [here](http://geryit.com/). I try to make something similar as in his menu links. I'm not asking for complete code, just point me to the right direction :) Maybe its only done with JavaScript?

Comment: CSS `:hover` pseudo-class, `z-index` and `relative` `position`ing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :after and :before in css

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Paintings</a></li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS**

```
body{background:black}
li a{
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: transparent;
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #fff;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5); 
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5); 
    -o-transform: scale(0.5); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5); 
    transform: scale(0.5); 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s linear;
    transition: all 0.6s linear;  text-decoration:none
}
li a:hover{
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
    -moz-transform: scale(1); 
    -ms-transform: scale(1); 
    -o-transform: scale(1); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
    transform: scale(1); 
    text-decoration:none
}
li a:hover:before{content:"<"}
li a:hover:after{content:">"}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XDHXt/1/)**

But this doesn't support IE but works with modern browsers.

---

**Answer 2**

Well I went through the site which you are referring and I found it is made of pure css (There are 2 images used in css). Find the Demo below (CSS is pretty long so I am not pasting here)

**[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/XDHXt/2/)**

Comment: Hi Sowmya, I improved my question, maybe you could help?;]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for. 10/10. Just for the record, How do you analyze the code from other websites? just looking to the simple source? or you use some plugin to analyse more clearly?

Comment: u r welcm. I look through inspect element and source

Answer (score 0):

1) First add symbols around every link in your template where you generate the link

```
 <li>
     <span class="slide">&lt;</span>
     <a href ....>
     <span class="sldie">&gt;</span>
 </li>
```

2) Set hidden by default and visible on hover

```
 .slide { 
      display: none;
 }

 li:hover .slide { 
      display: inline;
 }
```

3) Add CSS3 transition code to slide the hidden divs visible like here http://atomicrobotdesign.com/blog/htmlcss/slide-up-captions-using-css3-transitions/

The code is for example purpose only and is not from actually working product. But with these pointers you should be able to parse the effect together.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, but it does not work. Apparently -webkit-transition does not work well with "display" or even "visible". So the only way is to use small background img instead of <>?

Comment: I improved my question, please take a look when you will have time;]

Answer (score 0):

a variation of this would be to use "visibility" in place of "display"

```
.slide { 
      visibility: none;
 }

 li:hover .slide { 
      visibility: inline;
 }
```

This way, the text doesn't shift when the symbols are added. This may not look right depending upon your situation.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you are okay with transitions in Firefox for right now, and can wait for the Webkit team to enable transitions on generated content, this would be my suggestion:

```
body { background: #000; } 
ul li a { text-decoration: none; color: #fff; font-size: 2rem;
font-family: Avenir, sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; }

ul li a:after, ul li a:before { opacity: 0; font-size: 1.5rem; position: relative; 
top: -.25rem; color: #f00; z-index: -2; } 

ul li a:before { content: "<"; right: -2rem; } 
ul li a:after { content: ">"; left: -2rem; }
ul li a:hover:before, ul li a:hover:after { opacity: 1; transition: .7s all linear; } 
ul li a:hover:before { right: 0; } 
ul li a:hover:after { left: 0; } 

<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Paintings</a></li>
</ul>
```

[Code in Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/3928942). I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, its almost what I want to achieve. I have improved my question, please take a look on your free time;]